# Finding the greatest and the lowest value in an array using functions in C

Tags: c, arrays

I've written a program to find the greatest and the lowest number in an array of n numbers using functions.

I don't know where I got it wrong, because the code can't be compiled.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DIM 5

void lerArray(int x[DIM]);
int maximo(int x[DIM]);
int minimo(int x[DIM]);


int main(){
    int a[DIM],l,g;
    lerArray(a);
    maximo(a) = g;
    minimo(a) = l;

    printf("Minimo:%d \t  Maximo:%d ",g,l);

    return 0;
}


void lerArray (int x[DIM]){
    int i,numb;

    for(i=0;i<DIM;i++)
        printf("Intoduza o %dº elemento\n",i);
            scanf("%d",&numb);
            x[i]= numb;
}


int maximo(int x[DIM]){
    int i,max;
    max =x[0];

    for(i=0;i<DIM;i++){
        if (max>x[i])
            max = x[i];
    }
    return max;
}

int minimo(int x[DIM]){
    int i,min;
    min =x[0];

    for(i=0;i<DIM;i++){
        if(min<x[i])
             min=x[i];
    }

    return min;
}
```

The error I get is in line 13 `maximo(a) = g;` — the compiler outputs "`lvalue required as left operand of assignment`"

Comment: You need braces around the statements in your for loop in lerArray.  And it looks like you have your relational comparisons backwards in minimo and maximo.

Comment: And you need the following:     g = maximo(a);
    l = minimo(a);

Comment: When you say, "the code can't be compiled," you need to give the compiler output.  The errors will tell you (and us) what's wrong with your code.

Comment: First of all,Sorry I only noticed now that the functions are named in Portuguese. The error is in line 13 "  maximo(a) = g; minimo(a) = l;"    It outputs   "lvalue required as left operand of assignment;"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments:

```
maximo(a) = g;
minimo(a) = l;
```

should be:

```
g = maximo(a);
l = minimo(a);
```

And you need braces around your loop in lerArray:

```
void lerArray (int x[DIM]){
    int i,numb;

    for(i=0;i<DIM;i++)
    {
        printf("Intoduza o %dº elemento\n",i);
            scanf("%d",&numb);
            x[i]= numb;
    }
}
```

Also as mentioned by JonathanLeffler you don't error check the return from `scanf` and don't handle the case where the user doesn't enter all numbers.

The code below has those changes. It compiles and runs properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DIM 5

int lerArray (int x[DIM]);
int maximo(int x[DIM]);
int minimo(int x[DIM]);


int main(){
    int a[DIM],l,g;
    int count = 0;

    count = lerArray(a);

    printf("Numbers entered = %d\n", count);

    if( DIM == count )
    {
        g = maximo(a);
        l = minimo(a);

        printf("Minimo:%d \t  Maximo:%d\n",g,l);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Wrong number of entries.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}


int lerArray (int x[DIM]){
    int i,numb;
    int count = 0;

    for(i=0;i<DIM;i++)
    {
        printf("Intoduza o %dº elemento\n",i);
        if( 1 == scanf("%d",&numb) )
        {
            ++count;
            x[i]= numb;
        }
    }
    return( count );
}


int maximo(int x[DIM]){
    int i,max;
    max =x[0];

    for(i=0;i<DIM;i++){
        if (max>x[i])
            max = x[i];
    }
    return max;
}

int minimo(int x[DIM]){
    int i,min;
    min =x[0];

    for(i=0;i<DIM;i++){
        if(min<x[i])
             min=x[i];
    }

    return min;
}
```

Comment: The code should really check that `scanf()` is successful on each iteration, and should decide what to do about a short data set (only 4 numbers instead of 5) too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler good point. I just made the minimal changes to get the OP's code working.

Comment: Thanks.  I can't give a second up-vote.